# how to get rid of AdChoices (with system-wide adblocker)

Tags: macos, proxy, adblock

I hate ads.  I'm not used to seeing the internet with them.  Well one thing led to another and now I have ads again.  I am tunneling all traffic through a proxy running [GlimmerBlocker](https://glimmerblocker.org/) that has multiple ad filters.  I set up [custom hosts files](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/blob/master/readme.md) on both the proxy and the computer.  But still, [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z7bw.png) ads get through.  AdChoices.  How do I get rid of these particular ads?

Answer (score 0):

According to the developer, Glimmerblocker has stopped being developed because sites are switching to HTTPS which has unmodifiable content. You can't get it anymore on the app store due to policy changes, but Adguard will do the trick.  I think NordVPN's new desktop client also does it.